# How to Encode ASN.1 Context-specific using Openssl

Tags: c++, encoding, openssl, pkcs#7

I am trying to encode the pkcs7 encapsulated content info:

```
Sequence:
  OID
  [0] Context-specific
     OCTET STRING
```

My first problem is to encode Context-specific:

```
[0] Context-specific
```

So I tried to create a 'SET Context-specific' with 'Octet String', but without success:

```
// Create ASN1_OCTET
ASN1_OCTET_STRING *obj = ASN1_OCTET_STRING_new();
const BYTE* ptr = dataToSign.getData();
ASN1_OCTET_STRING_set(obj, ptr, dataToSign.getSize());

// Create ASN1_TYPE using ASN1_OCTET
ASN1_TYPE   *asn1Type   = ASN1_TYPE_new();
asn1Type->type = V_ASN1_OCTET_STRING;
asn1Type->value.octet_string = obj;

// Using i2d_ASN1_SET_OF_ASN1_TYPE
stack_st_ASN1_TYPE* sk = sk_ASN1_TYPE_new_null();
sk_ASN1_TYPE_push(sk,asn1Type);
int tamanho = i2d_ASN1_SET_OF_ASN1_TYPE(sk,(unsigned char **) NULL, i2d_ASN1_TYPE,V_ASN1_SET, V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC, IS_SET);
unsigned char* data = new BYTE[tamanho];
tamanho = i2d_ASN1_SET_OF_ASN1_TYPE(sk,(unsigned char **) &data, i2d_ASN1_TYPE,V_ASN1_SET, V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC, IS_SET);
```

I have not found documentation on the website of [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/).
This place is better [umich - Openssl documentation](http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/)

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Use i2d_ASN1_bytes function:

```
// Initialize ASN1_STRING inplace (no need to free)
ASN1_STRING s = { 0, 0, NULL, 0};
// Initialize with our data
ASN1_STRING_set0(&obj, dataToSign.getData(), dataToSign.getSize());

// Get resulting object length
int data_len = i2d_ASN1_bytes(obj, NULL, 0, V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC)
// Encode object with context tag 0
unsigned char* data = new BYTE[data_len];
unsigned char* p = data;
i2d_ASN1_bytes(obj, &p, 0, V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC);
```

Comment: i2d_ASN1_bytes doesn't exist anymore in OpenSSL. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6701

Answer (score 0):

> How to Encode ASN.1 Context-specific using Openssl?

From `asn1.h`:

```
#define V_ASN1_UNIVERSAL        0x00
#define V_ASN1_APPLICATION      0x40
#define V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC     0x80
#define V_ASN1_PRIVATE          0xc0
...

#define V_ASN1_BOOLEAN          1   /**/
#define V_ASN1_INTEGER          2
...
#define V_ASN1_UTF8STRING       12
#define V_ASN1_SEQUENCE         16
#define V_ASN1_SET          17
...
```

So you will need to use the tag `V_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC`.

> My first problem is to encode Context-specific

From [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apb/asn1.pdf) (p. 12):

```
> Example 1: PKCS #7's ContentInfo type has an optional
> content component with an explicit, context-specific tag:
>
> ContentInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
>    contentType ContentType,
>    content
>    [0] EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY contentType OPTIONAL }
> 
> Here the underlying type is ANY DEFINED BY contentType, the
> class is absent (i.e., context-specific), and the tag number
> within the class is 0.
```

Then, the document goes on to discuss the `ContentInfo`, the identifier octets, the encoding of `ANY` based on `contentInfo`, etc.